# Use case of Observable based paramMap approach

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-router

I normally use this way on [routes](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action) with my apps.

```
ngOnInit() {
  let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

  this.hero$ = this.service.getHero(id);
}
```

But above doc where I can see Observable based approach too.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.hero$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
      this.service.getHero(params.get('id')))
  );
}
```

Can you tell me why do we need this approach? Doc says this

> you only get the initial value of the parameter map with this technique. Stick with the observable paramMap approach if there's even a chance that the router could re-use the component.

But it is not clear to me. Can you tell me why we need an Observable based approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> you only get the initial value of the parameter map with this technique. Stick with the observable paramMap approach if there's even a chance that the router could re-use the component.

This means if there is a navigation event to the same component, Angular will not recreate the component since it is already available. Hence the ngOnInit won't be run again, resulting in ignoring the change in params(Snapshot only saves the first occurred value). In case of observables approach, it will be subscribed and change in params will be processed.

This use case should be considered, while you are displaying a entity like product and there is navigation button for relevant product.

Assume the url is "DOMAIN/product/1" and there is link for product 2. By clicking the link, the browser changes the url to "DOMAIN/product/2" but angular will reuse the product show component. The snapshot method will not notice the change due to above said reasons.

Answer (score 1):

That mean your way  will get only first value of param. But if you need to  handle params changes (for example filter changes which stored in query string) you need to  use second approach

Comment: Can you give more details about this? `filter changes which stored in query string`

Comment: So I'll try. For example  you filter component  on change  do  navigation to  another  route from `/route` to `/route?param1=test&param2=test2` without  route reload. And another  your component which render list of items have to  re-render list according filter value. So in list component  you need to subscribe to  `paramsMap` to be  notified about  filter changes

Answer (score 1):

you need a observable because if u have a route "user/2" and you have this aprroach

```
this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

when you in your url change 2 for 3 you value in `this.id` keep be "2" if you have this aproach:

```
>    this.id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
>       map((params: ParamMap) => params.get('id')),
>     );
```

you have a observable with your new user "id" because when you renavigate to the same route with diferent params angular dont destroy and recreate the component so ngOnInit is not triggered again when you change your param.